# How to add more web apps to existing windows azure web site

Tags: azure

I created a new web site on Windows Azure and chose WordPress from the Gallery to start the site. This is my company's website with my domain name. Now I want to add another web app from the gallery, let's say OpenX, on the same site so that it is running on the same domain. Does anyone know how to add another web app to an existing Azure website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new web site. Each web site can use different subdomains.
Your original page can be www.domain.com for example, and the new one can be something.domain.com.
You just need to register the name server entry for each subdomain as you did for the original domain.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about doing that and that is probably the only clean solution. I was hoping there was another way to do it without having to create subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create virtual directories. At the bottom of the Configure tab, there's a **Virtual Applications and Directories** section.  Just create a new directory and check the **Application** checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. I added the virtual directory and checked the Application Checkbox, but I don't see an option to choose/add a new web app from the web apps list. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just deploy your Web app in the directory you just created